# Block access to HashMap during refresh

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, hashmap, synchronization

I have a HashMap that is loaded from a database during setup. A change to the database triggers an update on the map. I need to clear out the entire map and reload it with new values. I need to block any other threads from being able to access the map's get method until the entire map is reloaded.

I cannot use a ConcurrentHashMap because the docs say:

> For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries.

I have tried using a synchronized block and a ReadWriteLock for the method that reloads the map but both still allow other threads to read from it. I cannot put a lock on each read because that would hinder the performance of my app.

All read access to the map is provided through a getter. I have considered using a Semaphore but I am not sure it is the best solution. Is there any other solution that would allow optimal performance without a major implementation change?

```
this.getMap().clear();
this.getMap().putAll(data);
```

Comment: *I cannot put a lock on each read because that would hinder the performance of my app.* Read locks are specifically meant for this. How do you know it would hinder performance?

Comment: What I mean is that I cannot use a synchronized hash map as that would only allow one thread to read at a time.

Comment: That's the point of a `ReadWriteLock`. Everyone reading from the map takes a read lock, which doesn't block other reads, and when you need to update, you take a write lock, which blocks reads and writes.

Comment: If the issue is just updating the map atomically, you can just just construct a new one and replace the (volatile) reference.